# How to obtain Role in Liferay Themes?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-velocity

How to obtain Role of a logged in User in Liferay Themes? How to check if User belongs to a particular role?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UserLocalService](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.0/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/service/UserLocalService.html) has `hasRoleUser` method which can be used to find out if User belongs to a particular role.
Below code can be put in `navigation.vm` file under `templates` folder.

```
#set($UserLocalServiceUtil = $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portal.service.UserLocalService"))
#if ($UserLocalServiceUtil.hasRoleUser(roleID, $user.getUserId())) // It takes roleID as input to check.
  //Proceed with whatever you want to 
#else
  //Proceed with something else
```

**Note:** Instead of `com.liferay.portal.service.UserLocalService`, if you use `com.liferay.portal.service.UserLocalServiceUtil`,
  as might be found in some resources like [this](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/196083) then you will encounter below exception,

```
ERROR com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.BeanLocatorException: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
  bean named 'com.liferay.portal.service.UserLocalServiceUtil' is defined
  com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.BeanLocatorException: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'com.liferay.portal.servi
ce.UserLocalServiceUtil' is defined
```

Another way is,

```
#set($role=$serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portal.service.RoleLocalService"))
$role.getUserRoles($user_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just loop through the $user object defined in init.vm

```
#set ($user_roles = $user.getRoles())
#foreach($role in $user_roles)
   $role.name<br />
#end
```